# Glitch in Facebook messenger unblocking?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am testing how blocking and unblocking works in Facebook social networking site and Facebook messenger. I have two accounts (says persons **X** and **Y**). **X** has blocked **Y** on Facebook messenger, while **Y** has blocked **X** on Facebook. Now, when I try to unblock **Y** from **X**'s Facebook messenger using the standard technique (given [here](https://www.wikihow.tech/Unblock-Someone-on-Facebook-Messenger)), one gets this message

```
This content is no longer available
The content you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may have expired, or you may not have permission to view this page.
```

When one tries this same execise on Android/IPhone , one gets the following error message `Error`.

Is this a glitch in Facebook's and Facebook messenger's blocking (and unblocking) algorithms? How can **X** unblock **Y** on Facebook messenger while **Y** keeps **X** blocked in Facebook?

Comment: Have you tried deactivating and the reactivating Facebook for X?